# Table [table name] has no column named [column name]

Tags: android, android-sqlite

My SQLite Database only had two columns at the beginning (ID and NAME) and now I have added two more: DURATION and DATE.

It seems like I have missed something because now whenever I try to write something to database it gives me the error mention in the title.

Here's the logcat output:

```
02-20 12:25:06.475: E/SQLiteLog(4907): (1) table music has no column named duration
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907): Error inserting duration=0 date=20.2. name=blahblah
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table music has no column named duration (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO music(duration,date,name) VALUES (?,?,?)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at com.matejhacin.beautifulvoicerecorder.database.DatabaseHandler.newSound(DatabaseHandler.java:32)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at com.matejhacin.beautifulvoicerecorder.RecordFragment$4.onClick(RecordFragment.java:198)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-20 12:25:06.479: E/SQLiteDatabase(4907):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Table query:

```
String music_query =
        "CREATE TABLE " + MUSIC_TABLE_NAME + " ("
        + MUSIC_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + MUSIC_NAME + " TEXT"
        + MUSIC_DURATION + " TEXT"
        + MUSIC_DATE + " TEXT"
        + ");";
```

Function for adding data to table:

```
public int newSound(String name, String duration, String date){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_NAME, name);
    cv.put(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DURATION, duration);
    cv.put(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DATE, date);
    open();
    return (int)db.insert(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}
```

I didn't forget to increment the DATABASE_VERSION variable. I even tried reinstalling the app completely.

Comment: Make sure that you did not update columns after inserting some data. Try after clearing application data, or re-install application.

Comment: I already did try to reinstall the application multiple times

Comment: it is just typo... you forgot commas in CREATE statment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Problem is you forgot to ad `comma` between two columns.***

Like `+ MUSIC_NAME + " TEXT"` should be `+ MUSIC_NAME + " TEXT,"`.

---

So your `music_query` string should be

```
String music_query =
        "CREATE TABLE " + MUSIC_TABLE_NAME + " ("
        + MUSIC_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + MUSIC_NAME + " TEXT, " // Need comma here
        + MUSIC_DURATION + " TEXT, " // Need comma here
        + MUSIC_DATE + " TEXT " // Need not comma here, because this is last column of table
        + ");";
```

Comment: Oh my...I could swear I went through these 7 lines of code over 100 times and I couldn't spot this small mistake. Thank you!